# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment when importing @google-cloud/storage

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am getting error when I import @google-cloud/storage in nodejs,

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

When I comment the line, everything works fine.
Below is the error I get:

> /home/trd/TRD/new-rapi/copy/676cb539092d21127ded33478d1073ab6886fc33/node_modules/pify/index.js:3
>   const processFn = (fn, opts) =
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^
>
> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
>       at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (/home/trd/TRD/new-rapi/copy/676cb539092d21127ded33478d1073ab6886fc33/node_modules/make-dir/index.js:4:14)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)

Comment: What version of node are you using? And does your code need to be transpiled? This seems like it might be related to your environment not supporting arrow functions. (I'm assuming that's what comes after `processFn = (fn, opts) =` but it's cut off so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a constant while importing.

I recommend you should use

let gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');

Replace "const" by "let" or "var". It should help.

Comment: declaring an imported class as a constant wouldnt let you change any variable in the class scope. Even if there aren't any, I'm pretty sure JS doesn't let you import a class as a constant to prevent a class trying to modify one of its own values (which would trigger an error on a constant.)

Comment: It also gives the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import the library like this example

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
```

A full example is in github [quick start example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js)

If the problem continue, maybe is related with your local environment I would recommend you try to set a clean development env in a linux VM and using Node.JS 10, this is in order to discard that the issue is related with any bad configuration.

Comment: @therightdoctors what version of node are you using? and could you share the function in which you are trying to import cloud storage?